# Find the number of times a value of an object property occurs in an array

Tags: javascript, api, rest

I have an array

```
const arr = [{
    name:'john',
    class:'tenth'
},
{
    name:'josh',
    class:'ninth'
},
{
    name:'ajay',
    class:'tenth'
}]
```

How to find out how many times ninth and the tenth has occurred in the array. But with the use of a single function so that I can have the data of the students of each class and show when my page is loaded.

e.g.:

```
X- 2
IX- 1 
XII- 9
```

etc

Comment: "class" is a reserved name in Javascript. you should use something else, like "className"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is what you want:

```js
const arr = [{
    name: 'john',
    class: 'tenth'
},
{
    name: 'josh',
    class: 'ninth'
},
{
    name: 'ajay',
    class: 'tenth'
}
];

console.log([...arr.reduce((a, c) => {
    if (a.has(c.class)) {
        a.get(c.class).count++;
    } else {
        a.set(c.class, { class: c.class, count: 1 });
    }
    return a;
}, new Map()).values()]);
```

Comment: Thats exactly what i needed .Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Example is below

```js
const arr = [
  {
    name:'john',
    class:'tenth'
  },
  {
    name:'josh',
    class:'ninth'
  },
  {
    name:'ajay',
    class:'tenth'
  }
];

// Create function to return number of matched classes
// *** We can't use word `class` as function parameter,
// so we use `cls` here
const getClass = (cls) => {
  // Match var
  let mTimes = 0;
  // Loop arr
  for(let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    // If matches request, count
    if(arr[i].class === cls) mTimes++;
  }
  return mTimes;
}

// Use
console.log(getClass('tenth'));
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try with next function. Sorry formatting not working on phone..

```js
Function groupBy(arr, prop) {
   const map = new Map(Array.from(arr, obj => [obj[prop], []]));
} 

arr.forEach(obj => map.get(obj[prop]).push(obj));
    return Array.from(map.values());
}
    
console.log(groupBy(data, "class"));
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use `forEach` I have used `rank` as a `key` instead of `class`

```js
var g={}
var count = 1
 const arrx = [{ name:'john',rank:'tenth' }, { name:'josh', rank:'ninth' }, { name:'ajay', rank:'tenth' }, { name:'steph', rank:'tenth' }, { name:'nick', rank:'tenth' }, { name:'ajay', rank:'ninth' }, { name:'ajay', rank:'ninth' }, ]
  arrx.forEach(o => {
    g[o.rank] = g[o.rank]||count
    g[o.rank] = count++
  })
  console.log(g)
```

Answer (score 0):

[Array.prototype.reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce)

```js
const arr = [{
    name: 'john',
    className: 'tenth'
  },
  {
    name: 'josh',
    className: 'ninth'
  },
  {
    name: 'ajay',
    className: 'tenth'
  }
]

function groupByClassName(arr) {
  return arr.reduce((cum, cur) => {
    if(!cum[cur.className]) cum[cur.className] = 0;
    cum[cur.className]++;
    return cum;
  }, {})
}

console.log(groupByClassName(arr));
```